# what is the difference between callbacks and listeners?

Tags: java

In blackberry we can override keyChar() method and capture the keypress event or we can register onKeyPressListener. i know, onKeyListener is observer pattern.

In android also there is a KeyEvent.callback and onKeyListener

Both are events why we no need to register for keyChar event.
what is the difference between both pattern?

Answer (score 15):

There can be many listeners for some type of event, but only one callback.

Comment: In android we can set only one OnClickListener to a view.

Comment: It's quite possible that their definition of "listener" doesn't match that of other products. Usualy, you don't have a "setFooBarListener()" method, but an "addFooBarListener()" method.

Comment: Another distinction could be that `callback` means a function (or closure or delegate), while `listener` is an object of a class that implements the corresponding Listener interface.

Comment: Vivart: doesn't matter, my answer isn't that good anyway

Answer (score -5):

I suppose that you have an application which use a library:

Listener: Library runs some code on its data, but, the code is implemented on Application.

Callback: Application runs some code on its data, however, the code is implemented on Library.

Because library can't see the application, so there is no way to instead Listener for that case.

Of course Application can see the library, but sometimes library wants to hide it's code, and helps application to make sense with it